# How to run a own function with clusterApply several times parallel

Tags: r, snow

I try to run my own function "EMGMM(y, startmy = 0)" with different parameters parallel:

```
require(snow)
library(parallel)

tasks = list(
    job1 = function(y) EMGMM(y=y, startmy = 0),
    job2 = function(y) EMGMM(y=y, startmy = 1),
    job3 = function(y) EMGMM(y=y, startmy = 2)
)

cl = makeCluster( length(tasks) )
clusterExport(cl, list("EMGMM"))

out = clusterApply(cl, tasks, ????)
stopCluster(cl)
```

But I don't now how I have to call "clusterApply". The y para is in each job the same and the startmy is a start para for the my algorithm.

Comment: Could you please include the code for your function `EMGMM` and some representative data?

Comment: Without a reproducable example, it is difficult to tell. However, what happens when you rewrite `jobX` to `function()` instead of `function(y)` and when you try `clusterApply(cl, tasks, function(f) f() )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks:)
y is a Matrix of multidimensional random variables

This worked fine for me (it's probably not the best solution):

```
require(snow)
library(parallel)

tasks = list(
    job1 = function(y) EMGMM(y=y, startmy = 0),
    job2 = function(y) EMGMM(y=y, startmy = 1),
    job3 = function(y) EMGMM(y=y, startmy = 2)
)

cl = makeCluster( length(tasks) )
clusterExport(cl, ls())
clusterExport(cl, "dmvnorm") #needed in EMGMM()

out = clusterApply(cl, tasks, function(f) f(y))

stopCluster(cl)
```